# How can I see Code Lens in Visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, codelens

How can I see Code Lens in Visual studio 2012? I don't want to install VS2013.I want to see how many references for particular method of class same as in VS2013?

Comment: You cannot as this is a feature of VS 2013 Pro of VS 2015

Comment: So any third party tool can i install for VS2012?

Comment: Resharper can do that

Answer (score 3):

You can't.
CodeLens is available only in **VS2013** and it also depends on the type of license (only in **Ultimate**). 
[VS license compare](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs).
For possibility to see how many references for a particular method of a class, I think you can use [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) functionality ("Find Usages").

Comment: and you need VS2013 Ultimate

Comment: So any third party tool can i install for VS2012?

Comment: Sure you can, but it can has some another functionality, not exactly the same as CodeLens. It depends what exactly you want.